# Getting corrupt zips using Python ZipStream in Django

Tags: python, django, zip, zipstream

I am a little new to Django so please bear with me.
I'm using zipstream from [here](https://github.com/allanlei/python-zipstream) and have a Django view that returns a zip file of all file attachments which are all hosted on Amazon S3. But the zip files are all coming up as corrupt when I download them, that is, I can't open them. I have tried verifying the files with `unzip -t` but the errors are not very helpful.

```
file_paths = [fa.file.url for fa in file_attachments.all()]

zf = zipstream.ZipFile(mode='w', compression=zipstream.ZIP_DEFLATED)

zip_subdir = "Attachments-%s" % (request_id)

for file_path in file_paths:
    file_dir, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)

    zf.writestr(file_name, urllib.urlopen(file_path).read())

zip_filename = "%s.zip" % (zip_subdir)

response = StreamingHttpResponse(zf, mimetype='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = \
    'attachment; filename={}'.format(zip_filename)
return response
```

Any ideas?

Solved it.

```
s = StringIO.StringIO()
with zipstream.ZipFile(s, mode='w', compression=zipstream.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    #could fail on url open.
    for file_path in file_paths:
        file_dir, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)

        try:
            file_contents = urllib.urlopen(file_path).read()
            zf.writestr(file_name, file_contents)
        except IOError: #connection cannot be made
            logging.error()

response = StreamingHttpResponse(s.getvalue(), mimetype='application/octet-stream')
response['Content-Disposition'] = \
    'attachment; filename={}'.format("%s" % (request_id))
return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close the `ZipFile` when you're done writing to it. Otherwise, to quote the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.close), "essential records will not be written" until you do.

The cleanest way to do it is using the `with` statement:

```
with zipstream.ZipFile(mode='w', compression=zipstream.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    # ...write to zf...
```

Comment: I've tried that and got this when testing the zip that still corrupt:

Archive:  22.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of 22.zip or
        22.zip.zip, and cannot find 22.zip.ZIP, period.

Comment: I have solved the problem, thanks so much! The solution has been edited in. Silly mistake...